# Encryption and Mutual authentication for Docker Containers?

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, docker, containers

I have two questions related to Docker container communication and security.

I have seen that *container-to-container* communication can be secured via **encryption** by enabling a secure flag.

1. Is this feature available for any stand-alone containers spawned via **docker run** on the default *(or custom made)* bridge interface?
2. Or is it only available in the **swarm-mode** amongst containers that are in the same overlay network?

And then, is there a similar feature to that of SSL mutual authentication amongst containers? As in to say, only containers with a certificate signed by a specific *CA* can talk to each other?

Or any other mechanism to restrict **what containers can talk to which containers** even when they are part of the same overlay network?

Thanks
Shabir

Answer (score 0):

> Is this feature available for any stand-alone containers spawned via
>   docker run on the default (or custom made) bridge interface?

It's not available on bridge and for stand-alone containers.

> Or is it only available in the swarm-mode amongst containers that are
>   in the same overlay network?

Yes that is correct. But encryption is between containers on different hosts. Container communication on the same host and same overlay is not encrypted.

> And then, is there a similar feature to that of SSL mutual
>   authentication amongst containers? As in to say, only containers with
>   a certificate signed by a specific CA can talk to each other?

This feature could be implemented at application level instead of Docker providing this feature at platform level. Docker does not provide a similar feature.

> Or any other mechanism to restrict what containers can talk to which
>   containers even when they are part of the same overlay network?

I think mechanism proposed above is completely reasonable for restricting access.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/overlay-security-model/

Comment: Are you sure that "encryption between containers in the same host" is not supported? The docker doc does not clearly state this. It says IPSec tunnels are created between the nodes in the overlay network. Doesn't that mean all the containers communicating over the overlay network (whether same host or cross host)  will have an encrypted channel?

Comment: From the reference link: "You can also encrypt data exchanged between containers on *different* nodes on the overlay network"

Comment: Does that negate the possibility of same-host-containers communication being encrypted? I would assume that since overlay networks stretch across multiple nodes and the encryption is specific to the overlay network and not the network that connects the host-nodes - everyhting is encrypted. But not sure.